# How to hide Html.ActionLink page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have code that when I run that code it will load values from the database into table like edit and delete (CRUD OPERATION).

Now I have added new html action link call 'approved'. The issue is I have column call `Approved` in the database the value only can store 0 or 1 - basically true or false.

My issue is when approved column 0 it will need to hide html action link when page load and when value 1 it want to visible on the page load. I can read from database but how to call html action link in to controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set style for ActionLink like this

```
@{
    var style = Model.Approved == 0 ? "display:none" : string.Empty;
}
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Approve",
    "Approved",
    null,
    new { @style = style });
```

Comment: Where We can add this code either controller or view or does need a controller to call?

Comment: so how to connect SQL Database i need to connect sql database get the value whether 0 or 1.i want to read and get that value then i need to check if approved=1 Link is visible else 0 not visible can you help me out solve this issue.?